# Move from CoPay Wallet to Coinbase

Tags: wallet

What is the current procedure (as of 12-8-17) to move/send Bitcoin from a CoPay wallet to Coinbase?

Answer (score 1):

Open a coinbase account -> get a 'receiving' address from your coinbase account -> send a transaction from Copay to coinbase. Right now the network is congested due to high traffic, so it may be worth waiting to make this transaction if you'd like to save money on fees. Getting a quick confirmation right now will be expensive.